# Passing dates from db RESTful web API Best Practices

Tags: c#, sql-server, date, asp.net-web-api

So I have 2 types of dates in my db, `date (yyyy-mm-dd)` and `datetimeoffset (yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.ms+Z)`, and I was wondering what is the best practice to deal with it when I'm taking the data from the DB and passing it as a json to the UI/mobile.

I used to always parse dates to `datetimeoffset` so normal dates will be something like `2018-09-24T00:00:00.000+00:00` instead of simply `2018-09-24` but it works perfectly with `datetimeoffset` that are already saved like that in the DB

Comment: Depends on your use-case.

Comment: @Strike08 can you explain a bit what you mean so I can provide you the details you need

Comment: The better idea is always use the datetimeoffset (yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.ms+Z) when you are returning from the API and in the client side you can do the appropriate date conversions.

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV I thought so as well but the decision isn't fully mine so I need to present solutions for both cases ( if I'm gonna stick to 1 format or 2) and then my superior takes such decisions.

Comment: Then you can go for different View models in this case , one with datetime and another one with string and based on your conditions you can assign the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In multiple ways you can handle this situation.

1 : From API side always give predefined date format value

Example `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.ms+Z`

And from the client side based on conditions you can convert it.

2: Keep different View models/ Properties may be for storing `yyyy-mm-dd` you can give `string` data type and for  `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.ms+Z` just `DateTime` . and based on your db you can write a condition and map the particular data.

3: Keep a single property for returning the date and make it as `string`

Example : `Public string CurrentDate{get;set;}` and you can simply map the database values(Conversion should be done). In this case client no need to worry about the date conversions they can simply show what ever you are passing from the api.

Note : The method 3 is not preferable because in the case in some places the user may see  `yyyy-mm-dd` in some other places `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.ms+Z`.

Comment: I think I will be going with the 2nd approach, for detailed dates I will keep it just `DateTime` while the short dates `yyyy-mm-dd`  I will use something like this
    `public DateTime VacationDateString { get { return CommonUtils.ConvertDateToString(VacationDate); } set {; } }`
    `public DateTime VacationDate;`

Comment: If you are ok with showing different formats in the ui then you can go for that.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [SQL Server Data Type Mappings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mapping)
You will see that SQL Server's `Date`, `DateTime` and `DateTime2` all map to .Net's `DateTime` data type,
and `DateTimeOffset` maps to `DateTimeOffset`.

> ```
> SQL Server Database Engine type             .NET Framework type
> date (SQL Server 2008 and later)            DateTime
> datetime                                    DateTime
> datetime2 (SQL Server 2008 and later)       DateTime
> datetimeoffset (SQL Server 2008 and later)  DateTimeOffset
> ```

Comment: I'm trying to use DateTime for dates but I get this as a result
`"vacationDate": "2015-02-06T00:00:00",`

Comment: I don't want the 00:00:00 to show when I'm passing the date in my json (to the UI or so)

Comment: Not really sure what "this" means here. the .Net framework does not have a data type for "Date" - you can try Noda Time if you want a data type only for date.

Comment: The ``00:00:00` can always be dismissed when creating a string representation of the date, simply use `DateTimeInstance.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")` and you're good to go